# Access an AWS EC2 instance from Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, couchdb

I have a static website hosted in a Amazon S3 bucket. The website uses PouchDB (javascript) to get data from a (Bitnami) CouchDB hosted in a EC2 instance.

The EC2 instance's inbound rules is configured to allow traffic for SSH, HTTP, .. including CouchDB port, 5984.

I could open the (EC2 hosted) CouchDB (Fauxton) from a browser, able to create / modify stuff, but the javascript in static website from S3 is unable to access the EC2.

The PouchDB throws error 'Timed out'.

Do I need to configure any other stuff in EC2?

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that the static web page (running on your computer in a browser) is trying to connect to a remote CouchDB on port 5984 to synchronize to the backend? Are any errors showing in the browser Console? What are the security group settings on the EC2 instance -- is it allowing 5984 from `0.0.0.0/0`?  You'll need to provide more information for anyone to be able to assist you.

Comment: The static website is not in my computer, but hosted in S3.. Yes, I am trying to connect to remote CouchDB (I was earlier using smileups free CouchDB hosting, it was working perfectly fine..).. Yes, as mentioned in my query, my instance is allowing 5984 port for 0.0.0.0.. Hope this helps!

Comment: Is your DB instance in a public subnet and reachable from the internet?

Comment: The "static website" is downloaded from S3, but runs in your browser. No code runs on Amazon S3. Therefore, it is the browser on your computer (running the code downloaded from S3) that is attempting to reach the back-end database. If you put your browser in [Developer Mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/), can you see any errors in the Console? Does the Network tab show the timeouts?

Comment: Have you enable CORS? You need to enable this if your pouch client is trying to access another host.

Answer (score 1):

S3 is a **Simple Storage Service**, can only be used to store data. Nothing runs on S3. The website you are serving from S3 runs on your local system. Configure EC2 instance to accept traffic from web i.e allow **0.0.0.0/0** in the security group.

Comment: I have done all the above config suggestions.. CORS is enabled, EC2 instance is open on all known ports, including 5984 (used by CouchDB). The PouchDB still throws error (in chrome devtool console) 'Timed out'

Comment: Found the issue... the culprit is corporate firewall / proxy in my company, from which I try to access the website.. The site runs fine when opened in my mobile.. Thanks for all your answers